# async await execution order problems with httpclient

Tags: c#, async-await, task, using

In our application we use *async* calls. These calls we need to wait for so we use await. But we notice that the application continues the application some where else on a await from the `HttpClient.SendAsync`. We reproduced it with the following code:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncExperiment
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1");
            var adapter = new Adapter();
            Console.WriteLine("2");
            var result = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => adapter.Start()).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("21");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Adapter
    {
        public async Task<string> Start()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("3");
            return await CollectionAccessor.ExecuteWithinScope(async collection => {
                Console.WriteLine("8");
                var adapter = new AsyncSearchAdapter();
                Console.WriteLine("9");
                var result = await adapter.GetSearchAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("19");
                Console.WriteLine(result);
                Console.WriteLine("20");
                return "";
            });    
        }
    }

    public class Client
    {

        public async Task<string> Get()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("12");
            var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://22ad5e1e-688d-4ba4-9287-6bb4a351fd05.mock.pstmn.io/test");
            Console.WriteLine("13");
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("14");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
            Console.WriteLine("15");
            if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode){
               Console.WriteLine("16a");
               return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();     
            }
            Console.WriteLine("16b");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class AsyncSearchAdapter
    {
        public async Task<string> GetSearchAsync()
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("10");
            var client = new Client();
            Console.WriteLine("11");
            var response = await client.Get();
            Console.WriteLine("17");
            if(response.Equals("{'test', 'test'}")){
                Console.WriteLine("18a");
                return response;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("18b");
            return response;
        }
    }

    public static class CollectionAccessor
    {

        public static TReturn ExecuteWithinScope<TReturn>(Func<ICatalogCollection, TReturn> func)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("4");
            if(func == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("func");
            Console.WriteLine("5");

            using(var catalogCollection = Resolver())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("7");
                return func(catalogCollection);
            }
        }

        public static ICatalogCollection Resolver()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("6");
             return new CatalogCollection();
        }
    }

    public interface ICatalogCollection: IDisposable
    {
        string notImportant { get;}
    }

    public class CatalogCollection : ICatalogCollection, IDisposable
    {
        public string notImportant { get;}

        public CatalogCollection(){ 
            notImportant = "test";
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }


}
```

We expect the order of the logs to be

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21
```

but we get the order like this:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,21,15,16,17,18,19,20
```

Could someone explain to me why this is happening in this order. And how to get it in the expected order?

Thanks!!!

Comment: There is no reason why you should be spinning up a CPU-based thread via `Task.Run()` when it is just going to eventually call a true async IOCP method `await httpClient.SendAsync()`.  You should be bubbling that `Task` up and toss the `Task.Run()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running async function (`adapter.Start()`) and not waiting for it. Try to change

```
  var result = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => adapter.Start()).Result;
```

to

```
 var result = adapter.Start().Result;
```

or

```
 var result = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => adapter.Start().Result).Result;
```

and I guess you are doing same problem here

```
await CollectionAccessor.ExecuteWithinScope(async collection => {...})
```

just ensure that `CollectionAccessor.ExecuteWithinScope` will handle awaiting passed function into it. Like

```
async Task CollectionAccessor.ExecuteWithinScope(Func <ICollection, Task> action)
{
    ...
    await (action(collection));
    ...
}
```

or at least returning it

```
async Task CollectionAccessor.ExecuteWithinScope(Func <ICollection, Task> action)
{
    ...
    return  (action(collection));       
}
```

**UPD**

Right here

```
public static TReturn ExecuteWithinScope<TReturn>(Func<ICatalogCollection, TReturn> func)
{
    Console.WriteLine("4");
    if (func == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("func");
    Console.WriteLine("5");

    using (var catalogCollection = Resolver())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("7");
        return func(catalogCollection); // <<<<<<<HERE
    }
}
```

you are creating Task which is not finished yet and you returning it and disposing collection before task fininshed. 
I guess you need to wait task for complete and only after it return it. Like

```
public static async Task<TReturn> ExecuteWithinScope<TReturn>(Func<ICatalogCollection, Task<TReturn>> func)
{
    Console.WriteLine("4");
    if (func == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("func");
    Console.WriteLine("5");

    using (var catalogCollection = Resolver())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("7");
        return await func(catalogCollection); // waiting task for completition
    }
}
```

**OR** you need to dispose collection inside task, like

```
public static TReturn ExecuteWithinScope<TReturn>(Func<ICatalogCollection, TReturn> func)
{
    Console.WriteLine("4");
    if (func == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("func");
    Console.WriteLine("5");

    //using (var catalogCollection = Resolver()) // not in using!
    {
        var catalogCollection = Resolver();
        Console.WriteLine("7");
        return func(catalogCollection);
    }
}
```

And then

```
    return await CollectionAccessor.ExecuteWithinScope(async collection =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("8");
        var adapter = new AsyncSearchAdapter();
        Console.WriteLine("9");
        var result = await adapter.GetSearchAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("19");
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.WriteLine("20");

        collection.Dispose();  //// Disposing!
        return "";
    });
```

From my point first approach (`await func(catalogCollection);`) - is best one

Comment: or `.StartNew(async () => await adapter.Start())`

Comment: @JamesThorpe yep yep, or `Task.Run` or something similar which will wait for results :)

Comment: I cant call result on the adapter.Start() this results in an exception. When i use async () => await method it doesnt solve my problem

Comment: @peterfeij which exception?

Comment: It gives an aggregate exceptions saying the method is not implemented.

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek I dont have problem if you talking with me :) And this is was already proposed

Comment: @peterfeij so, maybe you need to remove `throw new NotImplementedException();` from `Dispose` method of `CatalogCollection` calss to not throw this?

Comment: In our real application we saw the same behavior as in my example code but the Task was start with an await like this : await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => adapter.start()); but it still results in the same problem.

Comment: @tym32167 your right. but this exactly indicates the problem at our real application which is that the collection gets disposed before all code in the using is executed. In our real application there is some code that needs this collection after the HttpResponse.ReadAsync. but since the collection is disposed it cant

Comment: @peterfeij did you tried code which I proposed in my answer? Did you removed throwing exception from you code? Just try it, think it will work fine

Comment: @peterfeij if you dont want to dispose collection - dont do this :) I dont get your problem with collections

Comment: it gets automaticly disposed when it shouldnt. thats the problem. because the async order gets messed up somewhere

Comment: @tym32167 thanks i think this explains my problem. thank you for your patience and explanation. Im going to fix it after my lunch break

Comment: @peterfeij bone appetit :)

Comment: If you are not passing custom TaskScheduler then you should use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`

Comment: @tym32167 no, I meant OP :)